# JavaFX 8 Screen resolution doesn't update when program is running

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8, screen-resolution

For some reason when I print my laptop's resolution width using `Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getWidth());` I get the right result of 1920. But if I print the resolution width, change the resolution to 1680x1050 in Windows Settings, ask the thread to wait a minute, and print the resolution width again using the same code, I get 1920 instead of 1680! However, if I stop the project, set the resolution to 1680x1050, then compile and run the project, it does print 1680. In other words it seems that the project doesn't update the resolution if I change it while the project is running.

Below is some JavaFX code to illustrate what I mean. If I run the code below, watch it print 1920, change the resolution real quick, wait until the thread is done sleeping, then as described before it will still print 1920 instead of the new resolution width.

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getWidth());
        Thread.sleep(60000);
        System.out.println(Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getWidth());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this on a recent version of JavaFX?

Comment: It turns out I was using JavaFX 8 (IntelliJ refers to it as JavaFX 2.0 for some reason). Thanks for the comment. I updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has to do with polling the screen resolution on the same thread. If a new thread is created, told to sleep while the user changes the screen resolution in Windows Settings, and then told to print the screen resolution the screen, the resolution will reflect the updated resolution.

If the user ran the following and changed the resolution while the thread is asleep then the correct updated resolution would print to screen, unlike the code in the original question.

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getWidth());
        new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                try{
                    this.sleep(30000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // ignore
                }

System.out.println(Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getWidth());
            }
        }.start();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Another solution that also reflects an updated screen resolution is to use AWT. The following would print the correct updated resolution,

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

System.out.println(java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        Thread.sleep(30000);

System.out.println(java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```